# Using JSON data to set parameters inside servlet

Tags: java, json, servlets, jakarta-ee

I was unable to find any tutorials covering my exact problem so I'm posting my question here

I have a `poll.json` file

```
{
    "poll": {
        "title": "About your preferences",
        "questions": [
            "Which color do you like best?",
            "What is your lucky number?",
            "Why?"
        ]
    }
}
```

I want to grab the "title" content from the table and set it as the value inside h1 tag within the body as so:

```
out.println("<h1>Servlet NewServlet at " + title + "</h1>");
```

Here is my attempt. I know most likely I'm way off but I do not even know where to start with this problem

here is `PollServlet.java` :

```
protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
        try (PrintWriter out = response.getWriter()) {
            /* TODO output your page here. You may use following sample code. */
            out.println("<!DOCTYPE html>");
            out.println("<html>");
            out.println("<head>");
            out.println("<title></title>");            
            out.println("</head>");
            out.println("<body>");
            out.println("<h1>" + title here + "</h1>");
            out.println("</body>");
            out.println("</html>");
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        processRequest(request, response);
        getClass().getResourceAsStream("poll.json");
            String jsonString = "" ;
            JsonReader reader = Json.createReader(new StringReader(jsonString));
            JsonObject jsonObject = reader.readObject();
            String title = jsonObject.getJsonArray("poll").getJsonObject(1).toString();

    }
```

Comment: Instead of printing title, I can see in code you are printing request?

Comment: Did you debugged to see what is inside `jsonObject`?

Comment: @henriqueromao no, honestly I don't even know if I'm suppose to insert the code inside the doGet() method

Comment: `JsonReader reader = Json.createReader(new StringReader(jsonString));` currently reads an empty String

Comment: @Ishnark yeah I see that, what is the correct way of setting the reader?

Comment: Use JsonParser to parse the file into an Object. See CrunchifyJSONReadFromFile.java in (https://crunchify.com/how-to-read-json-object-from-file-in-java/)

Comment: @Ishnark do I add this inside doGet () and if yes how do I call the output from inside the process request method

Comment: Please, can you confirm if you are receiving the json through a post/get request or is it a file that exists on the server? If it is on the server iwhere is it located, in which folder?

Comment: @Juan I cannot confirm that i'm receiving the json since I don't even know how to do it proper. the file is located in project folder on localhost so localhost8080/poll/poll.json

Comment: It is your project, you should know if the file is going to be sent from a remote client, or if it is a server configuration file that will be put on the server by a developer and managed manually on the server.

Comment: Try moving the file to the source folder where you have your servlet and see it if picks it up.

Comment: @Juan no change, I think the whole thing is done wrong so no surprise

Answer (score -1):

To read the json object from the request I do:

```
StringBuffer jb = new StringBuffer();
String line = null;
AjaxActionRequestMessage actionReqMessage= null;
        try {
            BufferedReader reader = request.getReader();

            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null){
              jb.append(line);
            }
            actionReqMessage = new Gson().fromJson(jb.toString(), AjaxActionRequestMessage.class);
        } catch (Exception e){
              e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

AjaxActionRequestMessage is a class that mirrors the json your receive which can be instantiated using gson.

Comment: thanks for the answer. could you implement your answer in my code since I'm not even sure where to insert this code

Comment: If you are sending the json using POST it goes in doPost(), otherways in doGET();

Comment: and where are you specifying the path to the file

Comment: right here I getClass().getResourceAsStream("poll.json");

Comment: here is the path to the file: C:\Users\user\Documents\NetBeansProjects\assignments\poll\poll.json